# Dealing with lexer ambiguity: different lexer rules in context

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm building a ANTLR4 grammar to parse a custom language which looks like:

```
start rule_set {
    /foo/bar {
        //some_rules
    }
}
```

Where `/foo/bar` is a URL-like path so it may contain escaped characters (eg. `%20`) and other symbols. But `rule_set` part is a normal identifier and `%` shouldn't be in there.

Here is my current grammar:

```
grammar TEST;

start: 'start' IDENTIFIER block EOF;

block: LBRACE matcher* RBRACE;

matcher: matchPath matchBlock;

matchBlock: LBRACE RULES RBRACE;

matchPath: ('/' pathSegment)+;

pathSegment: (PATH_CHAR)+;

LBRACE: '{';
RBRACE: '}';
RULES: '//some_rules';

fragment LETTER : 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' ;
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' ;
fragment URLHEX: ('%' [a-fA-F0-9] [a-fA-F0-9]);

PATH_CHAR
    : URLHEX
    | LETTER
    | DIGIT
    | '-'
    | '_'
    | '.'
    | '!'
    | '~'
    | '*'
    | '\\'
    | '\''
    | '('
    | ')'
    | ':'
    | '@'
    | '&'
    | '='
    | '+'
    | '$'
    | ',';

IDENTIFIER: (LETTER | '_') ( LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*;

WS: ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' )+ -> skip;
```

The problem now is `foo` and `bar` are lexed as `IDENTIFIER` because it's the longest match. I want `pathSegment` to get correct result in this scenario. How to resolve this ambiguity?

```
[@0,0:4='start',<'start'>,1:0]
[@1,6:13='rule_set',<IDENTIFIER>,1:6]
[@2,15:15='{',<'{'>,1:15]
[@3,21:21='/',<'/'>,2:4]
[@4,22:24='foo',<IDENTIFIER>,2:5]
[@5,25:25='/',<'/'>,2:8]
[@6,26:28='bar',<IDENTIFIER>,2:9]
[@7,30:30='{',<'{'>,2:13]
[@8,40:51='//some_rules',<'//some_rules'>,3:8]
[@9,57:57='}',<'}'>,4:4]
[@10,59:59='}',<'}'>,5:0]
[@11,62:61='<EOF>',<EOF>,7:0]
line 2:5 mismatched input 'foo' expecting PATH_CHAR
line 2:9 mismatched input 'bar' expecting PATH_CHAR
```

Comment: Why not match `/foo/bar` as a single token? Or even do something like this: `pathSegment: (PATH_CHAR | IDENTIFIER)+;`?